# NodeJS callback is calling too early

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am running the following two functions one after the other. When runScript() finishes the callback function should be triggered. However these functions are running asynchronously, and data from the first function (which is required for the second function) returns as undefined.

I am new to callback functions, and am possibly approaching this incorrectly. I've omitted insertAssets() and insertPairs() for clarity, but their code is asynchronous and involves DB calls.

```
function runScript(cb) {
    for(var name in exchange_objects) {
        insertAssets(exchange_objects[name].assets, name); // runs some async code
    }
    cb();
}

runScript(function() {
    for(var name in exchange_objects) {
        insertPairs(exchange_objects[name].pairs, name); // runs some async code
    };
});
```

Comment: you need to use callback on those async calls currently you are just executing cb() without waiting for those async call to complete

Comment: i do not think 'for loop' can be used for async function calls. replacing with  https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each may help